# FullCalendar custom button icon not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

```js
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
         header: {
                    left: /*'prev,next'*/'BackwardButton,ForwardButton',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: '',
                },             
                customButtons: {                    
                    ForwardButton: {
                        //text: 'Framåt',
                        click: function () {
                        
                        }
                    },
                    BackwardButton: {
                        //text: 'Bakåt',
                        click: function () {
                         
                            



                        }
                    }
                },
                                buttonsIcons: {
                    BackwardButton: 'left-single-arrow',
                    ForwardButton: 'right-single-arrow',
                },
      
      });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.js"></script>



<div id="calendar"></div>
```

I am working with [FullCalender.io](https://fullcalendar.io). I have two custom buttons that I would like to add the default chevron or arrow to. I found these [properties](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/buttonIcons), but I can't figure out where in the full calendar initialization I should put it. Nothing have worked so far. I only get the text 'undefined'.  Any ides anybody?

```
      jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'BackwardButton,ForwardButton',
                center: 'title',
                right: '',
            },             
            customButtons: {                    
                ForwardButton: {
                    //text: 'Framåt',
                    click: function () {

                    }
                },
                BackwardButton: {
                    //text: 'Bakåt',
                    click: function () {

                }
            },
            buttonsIcons: {
                BackwardButton: 'left-single-arrow',
                ForwardButton: 'right-single-arrow',
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you provide an example code or an jsFiddle?

Comment: Added jsFiddel example of my error

Comment: Actually I was a wrong, sorry, deleted that comment. There's nothing wrong with your code except it's `buttonIcons` not `buttonsIcons`. You can add the icon there or in the `icon` property of the button definition. It's just a typo.

Comment: I saw an example with the same syntax as this `buttonIcons` when I was searching the web for an answer. But totally missed the `s` in my code.

Comment: Thanks for you help!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/510/ demonstrates it working. Note you need the latest version of fullCalendar (3.9)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:** the code below works, however OP's code was correct barring a typo (should have been `buttonIcons` instead of `buttonsIcons`). See @ADyson's JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/510/

**Original:**

I think this might be what you're after: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KoLZXq

It looks like you were trying to add the icons in the wrong place:

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: "BackwardButton, ForwardButton",
        center: "title"
    },
    customButtons: {
        ForwardButton: {
            icon: "right-single-arrow",
            click: function() {}
        },
        BackwardButton: {
            icon: "left-single-arrow",
            click: function() {}
        }
    }
})
```

Note how each button has an `icon` property now.

Comment: Thank you, sir! This was Exactly what I was looking for. Worked like a charm.

Comment: @AllramEst happy to help!

Comment: this works, and is one way to do it but actually so does the OP's code, barring a simple typo - see comments above.

Comment: i am trying to display calendar icon, but i can't , anyone has idea

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you need as an option in **fullcalendar**

```
themeSystem:'standard'
```

Comment: I will try your suggestion in future Projects.